# Declaration of cuda variables in header which is included in cpp project

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a class containing several variables only available when compiling with `nvcc`, such as `thrust::device_vector<>`. The class declaration itself is in a header file, the implementation of it is in a .cu-file. This class is to be included in the main project which is compiled using `g++`, which means that the compilation of the cuda-variables will also be done using `g++`. This fails, obviously. Therefore, I was wondering if there are solutions for that, i.e. that my class contains variables such as `thrust::device_vector<>`, but still can be included in the full project?
Can I somehow declare class variables only in the .cu-file, but not in the header file?

Comment: "This class is to be included in the main project which is compiled using g++". You can't do that. If it contains thrust it *must* be compiled with nvcc. If you have code which must me compiled with g++, then refactor

Comment: Two points I would like to avoid here, one of them is that I can't use C++17 with nvcc, and the other one is that I include mpi via some includes. That would also mean that I have to recompile every library I include which included mpi, something I would like to avoid...

Comment: So refactor. You have no other choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that my class contains variables such as `thrust::device_vector<>,` but still can be included in the full project?

You have to compile thrust containing code with nvcc. There is no alternative. If you include headers which include thrust into vanilla C++17 code and compile with a C++ compiler, you will get errors.

> Can I somehow declare class variables only in the .cu-file, but not in the header file?

You can do that, and it would be an obvious solution. But this then poses an equally obvious question of why you actually need the structure in the vanilla C++17 code in the first place. And if the intention is to use it in the C++17 code, then you are back where you started.

I see no alternative but to refactor your code. You either need to use inheritance from a common  portable structure with C++ and CUDA specializations and some way to copy construct or similar between them, or quarantine/warp all the C++17 code outside of the CUDA codepaths and use nvcc as your base compiler, and compile the C++17 separately with g++.

No amount of magical thinking can solve this in the way you seem to be imagining.

Comment: How would the inheritance look like, if I implement that approach?

Comment: That would depend completely on your code and your use case. I could imagine all the non thrust members could be in a common structure, with all the thrust members in a CUDA only specialization